# Angular disable debugInfoEnabled

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to disable debug info by putting `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);` in `angular.config()`. But why is that when I check in the chrome browser, I can still see the number of watchers with `angular watchers` plugin. It feels like the debug info is not disabled.

How can I disable it?

Example of my working code:

```
angular.module('app.core.config', [])
.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    // disable debug info
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}]);
```

Comment: What value are you getting when you run `angular.element(document.querySelector('body')).scope()` in your console?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal I get `n {$id: 2, $$childTail: b, $$childHead: b, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null…}`

Comment: Okay, can you please give me the link of the angular watchers plugin you are using?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal Here is the link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-watchers/nlmjblobloedpmkmmckeehnbfalnjnjk?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: That seems to working fine for me. Can you please add your code that how are you disabling the debug info and which version of Angular you are using?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal Thanks a lot for testing.. I have update my question with example of my working code. I am using Angular 1.4.3, the default angular that come with Ionic version 1.1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because Ionic [overrides the default behavior](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/af1bfef327e685585244c6051c4d38b98aa6c62a/js/angular/service/decorators/compile.js):

```
/**
 * @private
 * Parts of Ionic requires that $scope data is attached to the element.
 * We do not want to disable adding $scope data to the $element when
 * $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false) is used.
 */
IonicModule.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$compile', ['$delegate', function($compile) {
     $compile.$$addScopeInfo = function $$addScopeInfo($element, scope, isolated, noTemplate) {
       var dataName = isolated ? (noTemplate ? '$isolateScopeNoTemplate' : '$isolateScope') : '$scope';
       $element.data(dataName, scope);
     };
     return $compile;
  }]);
}]);
```

If you inject the `$compile` service you can inspect it and see that `$$addScopeInfo` is not the noop function as it usually is when debug info is disabled:

```
$$addBindingClass: noop()
$$addBindingInfo: noop()
$$addScopeClass: noop()
$$addScopeInfo: $$addScopeInfo($element, scope, isolated, noTemplate)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So, is that mean the debug info is not disabled with Ionic? Meaning, with or without `debugInfoEnabled(false)` makes no different?

Comment: At least that part of the debug info is still available in Ionic. I'm not sure if Ionic overrides every behavior of `debugInfoEnabled(false)`. You can for example check if the classses `ng-scope` and `ng-binding` are available or not on your elements in the DOM. Usually they are only added if debug info is enabled.